# vs2010 with juiceui juice a type not a namespace

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I get this error.

CS0138: A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Juice' is a type not a namespace

I installed via nugget instructions here

http://www.nuget.org/packages/JuiceUI

and tried this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="_Default" />

<juice:Datepicker  runat="server" TargetControlID="_Default" />
```

and I do have this in my web.config

```
<pages>
   <controls>
      <add assembly="JuiceUI" namespace="Juice" tagPrefix="juice" />
   </controls>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JuiceUI, but i think the problem here is the namespace given in your web.config, as there seems to be no namespace with the name `Juice`

you might want to look into the hierarchy of the JuiceUI library you downloaded (after double checking the reference in your project) and verify the namespace exists in the .dll you got from nuGet

my guess is you have to change the namespace to either:

```
JuiceUI.Juice
```

or

```
JuiceUI
```